# Javascript getting XMl data from external source

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to read the XML of an RSS feed on a website (that I do not have control over) and display it using Javascript. I used the following code to extract the data and it works, but the major caveat is that this will only work in IE 8 (Ugh).

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",<URL with xml extension>,false);
xmlhttp.send();
setTimeout("wait()",3000);

function wait()
{
alert("complete");
}
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
```

The wait function currently exists to give the server time to respond to my xmlHTTP request. Does anyone know a workaround in Javascript, AJAX or something similar that would give me functionality on current versions of Firefox, Chrome, etc?

Comment: if you didn't do the silly wait stuff, the code looks like it should work on all browsers, nothing IE specific here.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8 without the 'wait' code and it will not work at all on any other browser or newer version of IE with or without it

Comment: sure it will, use the readystatechange event instead of a fixed timeout. see just about any ajax tutorial for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [JFeed](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed), its faster and its really easy to use, your code is a bit long, with Jfeed you can do it like that:

```
jQuery.getFeed({
   url: '<URL with xml extension>',
   success: function(feed) {
      alert(feed.entry); //your element
   }
});
```

let me know if you need help with that.
Good luck.

Comment: I think its not worth the 3 sec time out, and the plugin works with all the browsers without problems.

Comment: i agree that the timeout is a mistake, but that doesn't affect the code weight; doing it right will only add 15 bytes in my testing...